# Boot script terminates and gives error (no error logger present) 

Tags: erlang

I made an Erlang application, that shall be started on booting of the operating system. The boot script is stored in /etc/init.d. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $ROOT/lib/di
INET_ADDR=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
NODE_NAME=$(echo di@$INET_ADDR)
erl -pa $PWD/ebin -pa $PWD/deps/*/ebin -name $NODE_NAME -boot di $1 -setcookie agfeo
```

The script tries to determine the IP address of the machine, in order to give the node an unique name. When the machine boots, the script gets executed automatically. On the terminal I get the following output:

```
(no error logger present) error: "Error in process <0.1.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_atom,[[<<2 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,46,98,111,111,116]]},
{init,get_boot,2},{init,do_boot,3}]}"
{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_atom,[[<<2 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,46,98,111,111,116]]},
{init,get_boot,2},{init,do_boot,3}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

This is what the shell prints out, when the script is loaded automatically. 
When I call the script manually, my application gets started normally, without any problems.

Could anybody please explain, what the error message above means?

Comment: Does this work when you run it manually ...i mean not at boot up...if yes then it has to be some path issues..might be erlang is not able to find its kernel lib ..thus error_logger ...just a guess..

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the stack trace the last function executed is [init:get_boot/2](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/erts/preloaded/src/init.erl#L748) and the last instruction is `erlang:list_to_atom([<<2 bytes>>, <<5 bytes>>, ".boot"])`. In the `init:get_boot/2` there are three lines with `list_to_atom`, so error should be one of the following:

- **'cannot get bootfile'**;
- '**bootfile format error'**;

I believe the error is **'cannot get bootfile'**.

Comment: The Erlang boot process serioulsy needs better error messages. :-)

Comment: That's a good starting point for further analysis. Thank you. I should definitely more often read the Erlang/OTP sources.